# software for non linear dynamic system simulation

Tags: matlab, simulation, scilab, stochastic

I am looking for a software package (free better) that can be used for stochastic dynamic system simulation with minimal coding. For example it should allow me to model a system by specifying:

```
Xn = AXn−1 + Vn, 
Yn = BXn + α Wn
```

where `X` is the state, `Y` observation, `A,B` matrices and `Vn` and `Wn` are noise sources with different pdf's such as normal, T, etc.

I've already tried `scilab` and `R`. Although they seem to be very powerful, it does not seem to provide direct support to create models by specifying above equations.

Comment: The system you describe looks linear to me.

Comment: yes, but in general i can be non-linear.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question - any programming language with a linear algebra package and random number generator can create such models. Can you give a more specific example?

Comment: coding is what i want to avoid. For example, BUGS/JAGS software allows you to define the model using set of intuitive equations. I am looking for a more mature alternative to those.

Comment: ah I see. This  is probably in the wrong forum to get an useful answer, as stackoverflow is about programming.

Comment: Did you look at scicos? It is a drag and drop modeling system, delivered with scilab. It is even able to generate c code from your model.

Comment: I have seen lots of questions asking for recommendations on tools,IDE's and so on in this site. This is a similar question. I do not think this Question is off-topic in that sense.

Answer (score 1):

If the noise is Gaussian, what you have is a [stochastic differential equation (SDE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation) written as a [recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation). If you're looking for something with "direct support" such systems you should specify what they represent physically – economic models, neural models, Kalman filtering, etc. – rather than just the abstract equations because such packages are generally written with an application in mind.

Matlab does have the [Econometrics toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/econometrics/) which is usually not included with most installs but can solve general SDE problems outside of finance as well. For a free option, you can also look at my [SDETools](https://github.com/horchler/SDETools) which is a Matlab toolbox for the numerical solution of SDEs that works very similarly to Matlab's own ODE solvers such as `ode45`. You will need to transform your recurrence relations to differential equations. And of course if you want the fastest code possible (stochastic simulations can be *slow*) it will always be better to code up the [Euler-Maruyama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Maruyama_method) method for your particular problem.

If you're looking for something that will do what you want without having to learn much about the underlying math you will most likely be out of luck. Also, if your noise is not Gaussian then the rules are different and you may need to learn about [jump processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_process) and the family of [alpha-stable distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Generally even the noise may be non-Gaussian.Additionally it should not be restricted to a specific domain. My requirement is to test a sequential monte carlo implementation with various models. The actual work is the implementation of sequential monte carlo and writing lots of code to test it is not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

"Open modellica" (https://www.openmodelica.org) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you. I will definitely look at this.

Comment: @suspension note: for future, you may get more answers to your questions if you get enough points to upvote answers, voting is important so most useful answers float to top.